# Setting the Hessian Threshold on Ptr<FeatureDetector>

Tags: c++, opencv, surf, hessian-matrix

Using this particular `FeatureDetector`, I can't figure out how to set the Hessian Threshold.

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
```

Anyone know how?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
float newThresh = detector->getDouble("threshold") + 3;
detector->set("threshold", newThresh);
```

Comment: hope your answer should be a little bit more descriptive so that everyone could understand.